IVP with solution not defined in at the initial condition
Given the IVP
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{\tfrac{3}{2}y^2+3x^2}{y^2-3xy} \\ 
y(0) &= -\sqrt[3]{3}
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Using
$$v=\frac{y}{x}$$
I found
$$
-2\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^3 
+ 9\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2 + 6 
= \frac{K}{x^3}
$$
as the general solution with $K\in\mathbb{R}$.
However I don't know if I made a mistake but certainly I can't use the initial condition $y(0)=-\sqrt[3]{3}$. Am I wrong or the exercise is not correct?
EDIT: I'm supposed to find the general solution, then the IVP one and in the end, find the interval in which the solution is well defined.

Shouldn't be $-2y^3+9xy^2+6x^3=K$?

Oh yeah, thank you for catching my mistake. I deleted the comment (and this one will go in a few minutes too).

Using the change of variables $$u=\dfrac{y}{x}$$
you are assuming $x\neq 0$. This obviously does not work for the above IVP.
Cross-multiplying one gets the equation $$\left(\frac{3}{2}y^2+3x^2\right)dx-(y^2-3xy)dy=0,$$
which is exact and has as a general solution $$\frac{3}{2}xy^2+x^3-\frac{y^3}{3}=C, \space C\in\mathbb{R}$$
Plugging in the initial condition $y(0)=-\sqrt[3]{3}$ we find $C=1$, and the solution is defined implicitly as $$\boxed{\frac{3}{2}xy^2+x^3-\frac{y^3}{3}=1}$$

If doesn't work for the IVP, why can I use $y(0)$?

Your change of variables does not work. Cross multiplying does, and so we can use $y(0)$
